# Select statement selects with no data

Tags: go

I'm writing a test in go that looks like the following example that is randomly passing or failing.

```
        t1 := make(chan []byte)
        t2 := make(chan []byte)
        done := make(chan bool)
        DoStuff(t1, t2, done)
        out := [][]byte{}
L:
        for {
                select {
                case d := <-t1:
                        out = append(out, d)
                case d := <-t2:
                        out = append(out, d)
                case <-done:
                        break L
                }
        }
        t.Logf("%s", out)
        if len(out) != expectedLength {
                t.Fail()
        }
```

The log shows that sometimes the `out` slice has empty elements appended to the end, could be any number, it's very random. The sending side it's sending what it's supposed to so I assume is because of the for loop and the select executing the branches after they have been read. Also probably worth to mention, the channels are all closed at the same time when the done channel is written to.

Comment: The go routines that is sending the data on the channel is random. If it is not synchronized you never know if the data on the channels for slice is coming first or if the done channel received the value first.

Comment: Please post the code of `Dostuff` function so we can analyze your issue. Since it is not possible to reckon the issue from current code. Also it is not because of for loop.

Comment: "If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection." https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements

Comment: just a side-note: the more idiomatic way of implementing a done channel (if not using context), would be to have a channel of type `chan struct{}`, seeing as the `struct{}` type is defined by the spec as being 0 bytes in size